# The fast way to solve several identical matrices with different b's

Tags: linear-algebra

On a test, our teacher gave a bonus question.

"Solve the following systems of equations:

2u + v + w  = 0

4u - 6v        = 0

-2u+7v+2w= 0

"

No problem, but this was the first question of several. The left hand sides were all identical, same variables, same coefficients, while the right hand sides were every possible combination of zeros and ones.

System #     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

2u + v + w  = 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1

4u - 6v        = 0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1

-2u+7v+2w= 0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1

(Each system was written separately)

2^3=8 systems to solve. Very time consuming. At the bottom of the paper it said "You can do it the traditional way or the linear algebra way". Because I don't know linear algebra I did it the normal way. But I was curious and started to look into linear algebra, but still found nothing about a fast way to do this. When solving I used information from previously completed systems to speed things up, but I think that's not the intended trick.

What is this faster "linear algebra way"?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suppose is referring to Cramer's rule.

Comment: @user2697423 What is your math level? Personally I was thinking of the LU decomposition (see the wikipedia page on [LU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) and especially [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Solving_linear_equations)). But I doubt this is what your teacher really had this in mind.

Comment: Cramer's rule usually has bad numerical stability unless it uses a slower way to calculate the determinant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the "left hand sides" of the equations are the same, the $\textit{coefficient matrix}$ will be the same for all of your 8 systems. This coefficient matrix is $$A=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 & 1\\ 4 & -6 & 0\\-2 & 7 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$ There are then several ways to proceed to solve the different systems.

$(1)$ We can observe that $A$ is $\textit{invertible}$, so to solve $Ax=b$ we simply use $x=A^{-1}b$. This method requires computing the inverse, but for a $3\times 3$ matrix this is not so bad, and then you can use the same inverse for all 8 systems. This is how I would do it.

$(2)$ One could also use Cramer's rule. I won't go into too much detail, but more info can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule).

$(3)$ One could also row reduce the augmented system $[A\mid b]$ to solve $Ax=b$. Or, to speed things up, we could row reduce $[A\mid b_1\cdots b_8]$ all at once, where $b_1,\ldots,b_8$ are the vectors corresponding to the 8 different systems.